# TypeError Árbol de decisión Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Estoy intentando hacer un árbol de decisiones pero recibo un error que no entiendo (adjunto captura). Estoy siguiendo este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6t2g5mUvQlM

[image: El error que estoy viendo]

Comment: Prueba a cambiar el parámetro `class_names=map(str, Y.values)`

Comment: En su lugar recibo el error "TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: No entiendo por qué te sale ese error, pero en todo caso lo siguiente sería equivalente al map y no te dará ese problema: `class_names=[str(y) for y in Y.values]`

Comment: Ha funcionado, te lo agradezco mucho!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje de error menciona la siguiente información clave:

```
[... ignoro la parte no relevante ...]
--> 374        node_string += class_name
    ...
    ...
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.int64") to str
```

Es decir, en algún momento Python ha tenido que hacer la operación `node_string += class_name` y ha saltado el error de que no puede concatenar cadenas con valores de tipo `numpy.int64`.

Esto da a entender que si bien `node_string` era una cadena, en cambio `class_name` no lo era (que era lo que python esperaba), sino que `class_name` era un entero.

Mirando entonces tu llamada:

```
tree.plot_tree (arbol_enfermedad, feature_names=list(X.columns.values), class_names=list(Y.values), filled=True)
```

veo que el posible culpable es el parámetro que estás pasando en `class_names`, puesto que el error apareció al intentar acceder a una `class_name` como hemos visto. Se ve que la función `tree.plot_tree()`  espera que el parámetro `class_names` sea una lista de cadenas, y en cambio tú le estás pasando `Y.values` que por lo que se ve es una lista de enteros.

Por tanto la solución es convertir esa lista de enteros en una lista de cadenas, lo que puede hacerse con una *list comprehension* cambiando tu llamada a esto otro:

```
tree.plot_tree (arbol_enfermedad, feature_names=list(X.columns.values),
   class_names=[str(y) for y in Y.values], filled=True)
```